# Web Part that accepts users input and display the data

Tags: development, web-part, form

I am trying to create a web part that will accept data from a user and simply display it on the screen. I have researched and researched and i cannot get the data to display.

HTML

```
<div class="form-el-holder">
    <label for="oldHostUrl" id="old-host-url-label">Old Host URL</label>
    <input runat="server" type="text" id="oldHostUrl" name="oldHostUrl" />
</div>
<div class="form-el-holder">
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit" />
</div>
```

I do not have the form elements wrapped in a `<form>` tag because i received an error because there can only be 1 runat="server" form.

C#

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //MesgBox("Hi"); This just lets me know if the data will display in a message box
    // I have tried 
    Textbox obj = (Textbox)sender;
    // This does not work as i get an error when trying to access the .Text method.
    //I have even tried just 
    oldHostUrl.Text;
    // I receive an error because it doesn't know what to do with the .Text method.
}
```

There must be a simple solution but i cannot find one. Thanks for any and all help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `<asp:TextBox>` control for oldHostURL if you want to access the `.Text` property.

`input` elements are represented as [HTML Input Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7csdtts.aspx) in server side code. The specific type depends on the type attribute.

When using `type="text"` these become [HtmlInputText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext.aspx) which doesn't have a `Text` property. Instead you'll need to use `Value`.

`oldHostURL.Value`

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. I figured `<asp:TextBox />` and `<input type="text" />` would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Visual Webpart in Visual Studio. Once this done, you can drag and drop the text box and button from Toolbox.

Next double click the button which automatically creates an event handler. In the handler code you can write

```
OldHostURL.Text = TextBox.Text;
```

Comment: As i kind of mentioned in my post, i cannot use .Text. If i do, i get an error.

Comment: It seems you are using wrong project type? I have always got a toolbox and canvas in case of visual webpart. Which is your visual studio version?

Comment: Apologies, I do have a canvas. Even when i had the button and double click it and add your suggested code, i get an error.